# Batch / Bulk insert in R

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, jdbc, odbc

I am trying to do a batch insert in R using RJDBC. It seems like it inserts 1 row at a time which takes a lot of time.

I was wondering if anyone knows of a solution in R to do bulk insert data from R to SQL. I know RODBC can do parametrized insert which is fast but not as fast as bulk insert.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about your "R" language, but there is a BULK sql statement available in sqlExe.

sqlExe is a utility that connects to SQL databases via ODBC and will execute any valid SQL, plus it has some additional features ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlexe/ )

For example, assuming the target table is:

```
 table: [mydata]
 -------------------
 row_id      char(1)
 row_idx     integer
 row_desc    char(32)
```

To do your insert task with sqlExe you would prepare a file with your input:

```
  input.dat

    a,1,this is row 1
    b,2,this is row 2
    c,3,this is row 3
    d,4,this is row 4
```

The command line to import:

```
  sql --dsn MYDB -e "BULK INSERT input.dat, INSERT INTO mydata(row_id,row_idx,row_desc) VALUES(?,?,?)"
```